# MSSQL Check if column is all digits or empty

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a varchar field in a table. I have to check which rows contain anything but digits (0-9). Any other character (. , etc) are not allowed.

ISNUMERIC isn't helpful because the string can get longer than anything which would be convertible to a numeric datatype in SQL-Server.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why you are storing numbers as string in the first place?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  If the field is supposed to hold a number it should be a numeric type. On the other hand, those digits may be an invoice number or other business field. In any case, SQL isn't a good language for string manipulation. If you want to detect invalid data it may be better to use an external program to find invalid rows. If you want to create eg a trigger, perhaps it's best to create a SQLCLR UDF that uses eg `Int.Parse` or a regex. There may be other methods too, but none of them is going to be fast

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sometimes a string of digits has leading zeroes but not a fixed length. That doesn't work well as an integer datatype.

Comment: @HABO I explained this in my comment and answer. If it has leading zeroes, it's not a number. It's a business field whose value contains only digits. VAT numbers are such a case

Comment: its a business field as you correctly assumed. I have very little ability to modify the programm itself which is using the data, so I need to find the invalid data on the other end. Legacy code, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [PATINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to find and reject values with non-digit characters :

```
declare @t table (field varchar(40))
insert into @t (field)
values
('40340,033680998078'),
('40340'),
('033680998078')

select *
from @t
where patindex('%[^0-9]%',field)=0
```

This query can't take advantage of any indexes and will have to scan the entire table. It's best to avoid storing non-digit characters in that field in the first place.

In general, if a field contains numeric data it should use a numeric type, not varchar. It should be an `int`, `bigint` or `numeric(...,0)`.

On the other hand that field may be a business field storing eg an invoice number, airline ticket or VAT number.

In that case one would want to use a `CHECK` constraint to ensure invalid values can't be inserted in the table. This is possible using PATINDEX :

```
declare @t table 
( 
    field varchar(40) CHECK (patindex('%[^0-9]%',field)=0)
);
```

This check constraint will allow :

```
insert into @t (field)
values
('40340'),
('033680998078')
```

But reject :

```
insert into @t (field)
values
('40340,033680998078')
```

Comment: This works perfectly - I found out what was missing. There was an invisible newline at the end of each field. Replaced that - works fine now!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that "empty" means `NULL`:

```
Field NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
    OR Field IS NULL
```

Example to get values which contain only digits or are empty:

```
declare @test table (Field varchar(32))

INSERT @test
VALUES
    (NULL),
    ('121414'),
    ('88977665'),
    ('234234f'),
    ('347238748d9')

select * from @test
where Field not like '%[^0-9]%'
    OR Field is null
```

> ### Field
>
> NULL
>
> 121414
>
> 88977665

Example to get values which contain nondigit characters and not empty:

```
declare @test table (Field varchar(32))

INSERT @test
VALUES
    (NULL),
    ('121414'),
    ('88977665'),
    ('234234f'),
    ('347238748d9')

select * from @test
where Field like '%[^0-9]%'
    AND Field is NOT null
```

> ### Field
>
> 234234f
>
> 347238748d

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, using this, I get no resultset, even when there is data like '
40340,033680998078' in there, which clearly has some character which is not a digit.

Comment: @Stefan Wolf  Remove not from the final statement. The query should be Where Field like '%[^0-9]%'

Comment: Oh, my English is not so bad - your title and info inside the question are different, anyway, I have corrected my answer